# Page Numbering in "Exam" Document Class

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, exam

When using the "exam" document class, LaTeX prints "1" for the page number at the bottom of the first page but prints "Page n" for all successive pages where n is the page number. Anyone know how to fix this? I just want the page number to appear at the bottom of each page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 13):

The footer can be redefined with the `\footer{...}{...}{...}` command in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\footer{}{\thepage}{}

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A. Author}

\maketitle

\section{Section One}

\begin{questions}
  \question
  What if there were no air?

\end{questions}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem - I want the footer on EVERY page to be JUST the page number. For instance, the footer on page 34 should just read "34".

Comment: @RyanPeden Sorry, I misread your question. This should work now as requested.

Comment: @RyanPeden Welcome! If this answer is what you've been looking for, please consider to [accept it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/21591).